# Object recognition capture unable to find Pose

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 with ROS groovy configuration. I use a kinect on a USB2.0 port.

I would like to use the object_recognition package but I don't succeed in make the capture tool work.
I succeed capturing my textured_plane but impossible to have a 3D position displayed when I track the features.

Here is my command line for capturing my textured plane :

```
rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane --res sxga --fps 15
```

But when I try to see the position tracking, no position is outputed in the video

```
rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_track --track_directory my_textured_plane --res sxga --fps 15
```

But, if I show the matches, the features detection seems to work quite well.
[image description http://smartrobotics.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ORK_not_working-e1378824603329.png](http://smartrobotics.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ORK_not_working-e1378824603329.png)

So I try some different parameters (more feature points, less threshold ...) but the position never appears.

Does anyone have a clue on why the 3D position is not display while the features are correctly detected?

PS : I also try `rosrun object_recognition_capture capture -i my_textured_plane --seg_z_min 0.01 -o silk.bag --preview --res sxga --fps 15` but no object is detected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78086/object-recognition-capture-unable-to-find-pose/) by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [keavenM](https://answers.ros.org/users/3831/keavenm/) on 2013-09-19**:
Same problem here. (Ubuntu 13.04 ROS Hydro)

**Comment by [averybigant](https://answers.ros.org/users/6136/averybigant/) on 2013-09-19**:
Same problem （Ubuntu12.04 ROS groovy）

**Comment by [averybigant](https://answers.ros.org/users/6136/averybigant/) on 2013-09-24**:
hey guys, you can find further information on https://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_core/issues/17

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2013-09-24**:
Thanks, I will mail him to see if I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you ever tried:

```
rosrun object_recognition_capture capture --seg_z_min 0.01 -o silk.bag --preview --res sxga --fps 15
```

Omitting the -i parameter sets the capture app to use the printed markers.
This works for me!

Remark: The orb_template step is not needed if you omit -i.

It seems that there is a bug in orb_template or in capture when matching the features to the template's.

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [averybigant](https://answers.ros.org/users/6136/averybigant/) on 2013-09-27**:
Wow, it works for me! Thank you for your solution.

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2013-09-29**:
I will try this tonight but I wanted to use my own textured plane.

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2013-09-30**:
After a try, it seems that it works wih the standard template. I have upvote your answer but there is still a bug when using our own textured plane.